# Adding a dev mode

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement “Maintenance Mode” on already established website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396848/how-to-implement-maintenance-mode-on-already-established-website)

I realize it's not advised but what "quick and dirty" approach could be used to do maintenance changes to a web site such that are hidden from public view ?

Edit: To add more detail, the stuff I want to hide is what's being developped. The existing or established content should still show as if the site were live.

Comment: Thanks @j08691. Not exactly the same context (site is not mine and some page content should show) but answers apply.

Comment: Btw, do you think this question would better apply to the programmer's SE ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a .htaccess is more secure as it will handle ALL urls (php or not) :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !215.252.232.22
RewriteRule .* http://domain.ext/maintenance.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

this is dirty, but you could do something like replacing "##.##.##.##" with your IP:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=='##.##.##.##'){
    //test code
}else{
    // live code
}
```

Note: I do not advise doing this, but it is quick and easy.

Comment: This would (sort of) work if you had some way to add it to every PHP page (maybe via a global include?).  It also wouldn't prevent access to .html files, .png images, etc.  But the .htaccess suggestion in the comment to the OP I think is a better approach