# Trying to make a maintenance mode with PHP and a database

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I am running into an issue with my code since no matter what I change it to, it stays on the index page?

Here is my code

```
<?php
// Maintenance mode

$system = (mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system"));

if($system['maintenance'] == 1)
{
header('Location: /maintenance');
exit;
}
?>
```

I want it so if maintenance = 1 it would send you to the maintenance.php page but it doesn't can anyone help me with this? I tried,

```
if(!$system['maintenance'] == 1)
```

which works but I have this code in my maintenance.php page

```
<?php 
$system = (mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `system`"));

if(!$system['maintenance'] == 0)
{
header('Location: /index');
exit;
}
?>
```

What I thought would send me back to the index page once that in the database it shows it is a `0` or that's what I want it to do. Can anyone please explain why my code isn't working?

> I am a beginner php, mysql, and C++ coder / programmer so please try to explain it the easiest way possible.
>
> I fixed it thanks to @Script47.
>   New code and works

```
<?php
$system = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system");
$results = mysql_fetch_array($system);

if($results['maintenance'] == 1)
{
    header('Location: /maintenance');
    exit;
}
?>
```

The reason I do not need an extension for *maintenance* is because I have it set in .htaccess to ignore them, but for everyone to know it's a `php` file.

Comment: You need to fetch your results.

Comment: fetch your results inside your database.

Comment: How would I do that? Would it be something like fetch_array_ etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually fetch your results from the database. Look in to the link I provided. I will update my post with code.

```
    <?php
    $system = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system");
    $results = mysql_fetch_row($system);

    if($results[yourColumnKey] == 1)
    {
        header('Location: /maintenance.php');
        exit;
    }
    ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

**Edit 1**

Your code is prone to [`SQL injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you are still using `MySQL` even though it has been deprecated, you should use either `MySQLi` or `PDO` with prepared statements.

**Edit 2**

You don't seem to be specifying a file extension on your `header();`.

```
header('Location: /maintenance');
                            --^
```

What is *maintenance*? A `PHP` file? A `HTML` file? You need to specify an extension too.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding that, how would I implant that into my page the first code is all I have in that *.php file so would I do something like `mysql_fetch_assoc($system['maintenance'] = 1`?

Comment: Copy my code in to your file. Also in this part `$results[yourColumnKey]` change *yourColumnKey* to number at which maintenance show up.

Comment: @GrimmRP check **Edit 1**, also if this answer helped. Please press the tick.

Comment: Okay I put in the code you gave me and in the database I have it set at one shouldn't it be taking me to the maintenance page?

Comment: Grimm, can't you have Script47 combine that with your [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932991/how-to-put-a-site-into-maintenance) question from last nite ? Dagon wrote up something nice too. Oh, **nice job**, Script, by the way :>

Comment: @GrimmRP what is *maintenance*? Is it a `PHP` file? An `HTML` file? You don't specify a file extension.

Comment: @Script47 It's a `php` file yes, I have no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: @Drew thanks man. :) GrimmRP, please check the code again. Copy and paste it in to your file then try.

Comment: @Script47 Okay I did this, `<?php
    $system = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system");
    $results = mysql_fetch_row($system);

    if($results['maintenance'] == 1)
    {
        header('Location: /maintenance.php');
        exit;
    }
    ?>` but still no luck, it just keeps me at the index page I will add the top of my index page to show you I have it added.

`<?php require_once '/template/extra/maintmode.php';?>`

Comment: @GrimmRP which page are you running in your browser? The one I'm telling you to update?

Comment: @Script47 I am running, Index.php which I have the code `<?php require_once '/template/extra/maintmode.php';?>` which should bring the codes you are giving me to the index page. Shouldn't that grab the maintmod.php which I added your code to and check if maintenance is a 1 or 0 in the database?

Comment: @GrimmRP does *maintenance* actually equal 1?

Comment: @Script47 Yes in my database it's set as 1 or equal 1 I have it set as a `enum('0','1')` Is there away to show you my site and code etc? I have no idea why it isn't working..

Answer (score 0):

As you are a self-described beginner, it's probably best to learn how to do this using mysqli instead of using old deprecated code.

Below does essentially the same thing, but will last past the current version of php.  It's a good habit to get into.  (note if you are going to use any variables in your query, you will want to look up [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

$system = $conn->query("SELECT maintenance FROM `system`");
while ($row = $system->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row['maintenance'] == 1) {
         header('Location: /maintenance');
         exit();
    }
    else {
        header('Location: /index');
        exit();
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is, I have no idea how to update to mysqli since I am using xampp to host my folders and files.

Comment: This will work fine in xampp.  mysqli is included.

Comment: Okay I will try this code, also I already have my database fetched through a config file.

Comment: note as this uses object oriented style, the connection needs to work this way as well.

Comment: So I would have to type my database details into that also? Just getting this error now `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line 4`

Comment: yes.   if you are using `mysql_` connection, that will need to be changed as well.   all `mysql_` functions are deprecated.  It's pretty easy to use `mysqli_`.   (that's why I provided the connection detail)There are only some subtle changes to the syntax

Comment: oh and I made a typo. fixed  (ack, I always seem to do that ;))

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I got it working since @Script47 had it as row it wasn't getting it since it needed to be an array.

Comment: yes, that will technically  work.  However, as mentioned, it's a bad habit to get into for multiple reasons.  `mysql_` extensions are *deprecated*.  This means that they will soon *stop working*.   Also, they cannot handle prepared statements or object oriented approaches.   This means that you will have code that is a) not scalable, and b) more importantly vulnerable to sql injection.   I just wanted to give some pointers.

Comment: I will try looking into mysqli, I am using an old version of xampp since it was the easiest for me when I started coding back in 2011. This easy stuff which above people would look at and be like that is so damn easy but it is hard for me but boolans etc are easy for me. Thanks for helping (:

Comment: note @Script47 also mentioned this in his explanation.  I just wanted to help with demo. also note: mysqli has been available since well before 2011.   It was introduced in php version 5.0.0.   It definitely was in xampp in 2011 (I know, I use it).  Any way, good luck, and have fun :)

Comment: so I can use mysqli in xampp version or control panel version 1.7.3? If so I will try to learn it.

Comment: you can check with phpinfo().   if you have php 5.3 or above you definitely have it.  Also you may want to look into PDO, which is the current standard